# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected (Calling JS Function from Code Behind)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am trying to call a Javascript function from my code, but I'm getting the Object Expected js error.

My call to the function:

```
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "script", "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\">returnVal();</script>");
```

And my javascript from the .aspx

```
<script language ="javascript">
function returnVal() {
    var hidAppID = document.getElementById("hidAppId");
    var hidAppName = document.getElementById("hidAppName");
    var hidAppSox = document.getElementById("hidAppSox");

    if (window.showModalDialog) {
        var sharedApp = {};
        sharedApp.Id = hidAppID.value;
        sharedApp.Name = hidAppName.value;
        sharedApp.Sox = hidAppSox.value;

        window.returnValue = sharedApp;
    }
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

The javascript is valid - I added a temporary button to the page to test an "onclicked" call to it. Unfortunately, I need to call it from the code.

Comment: What's the generated source?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for: 
<script src="/ServiceRequest/WebResource.axd?d=7WM84Cl5TnKU_RJMH3HviqVFNhsBJZD1CgCdpmUUbwK95Ds3iKztpSGZ0NZJKRdPBAE2DiO33POpwVVSx_icHjCTkNY1&amp;t=634604208479085897" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/JavaScript">
returnVal();
<

Comment: Do you see the problem now?

Comment: it looks like i have an empty tag there at the end. should have seen that before. Do I have an escape character in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling it without embedded tags, but passing 3rd parameter instead:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "script", "returnVal();", true);
```

Comment: I still get the error. The generated code is:
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
returnVal();//]]>
<

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside of that JS function ad see if it is getting called at all and if it is - which line throws the error?

Comment: I do have a breakpoint but it isn't getting hit. I tried the same code you posted above, but "RegisterStartupScript" instead. I got the same generated code with an addition:

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
returnVal();Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
<

Comment: When is this script generated in you server-side code? And where, relatively to Update Panel is `function returnVal()` located?

Comment: My hardcoded script is at the bottom of the page (outside html tags). And I'm not using an update panel on the page. I just double checked to make sure.

Comment: Try to put function declaration within <HEAD></HEAD> tags

Answer (score 0):

You have put `\returnVal();` in the string, which makes `\r` the escape sequence for the carrage return character, so you will be trying to call the function `eturnVal`, which doesn't exist.

Remove the backslash from the code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "script", "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\">returnVal();\n</script>");
```

Comment: Sorry that was just copied incorrectly. It has been corrected in the OP